# EKRecurrenceRule with end repeat never

Tags: objective-c, ios, ekeventkit

I want to create a EKEvent in calendar with forever repeat option. Below is the code for the Recurrence rule

```
  EKRecurrenceRule *rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] 
                            initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily 
                            interval:1
                            end:[EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:date]];
```

how to set infinite or never end in recurrence end argument.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

little late, but i 'll answer, because i could not find the answer anywhere in the Apple Doc.
Just pass nil as end param and there you go. Calender sets the end of the event to infinite.

```
EKRecurrenceRule *rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] 
                        initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily 
                        interval:1
                        end:[EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:nil]];
```

The calender creates recurrence events for 2 years and then adds them on demand.

greets

Comment: recurrenceEndWithEndDate nil won't work. From Apple Docs: "The end date argument must be a valid NSDate and not nil; otherwise an exception will be raised."

Comment: if I want to set repetition every 2 week then how to make it possible using above code.
Can any one help me?

Comment: I got solution just pass 2 instead of 1 in "interval" parameter.That's it

Answer (score 2):

```
EKRecurrenceRule *rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] 
                        initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily 
                        interval:1
                        end:nil];
```

just pass nil to the end so that it repeats all over. Have a happy Coding.