# How to make repeating calender event in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, events, calendar, ekevent

Can anybody tell me how to make a repeating (weekly,daily,monthly) event for iOS Calendar events. My current implementation is something like this:

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

event.title = [cellValue objectForKey:@"ZEVENTNAME"];
event.notes = [cellValue objectForKey:@"ZEVENTDESCRIPTION"];
event.location = [cellValue objectForKey:@"ZLOCAITONname"];

NSString * dateStart  =[cellValue objectForKey:@"ZEVENTSTARTDATE"];
NSString * dateEnd =[cellValue objectForKey:@"ZEVENTENDDATE"];

NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *sDate = [_formatter dateFromString:dateStart];
NSDate *eDate = [_formatter dateFromString:dateEnd];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

event.startDate = sDate;
event.endDate = eDate;


event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

NSError *error;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
```

I have gone through developer help from apple but couldn't get the way how to implement.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the answer here: [StackOverflow: EKRecurrenceRule with end repeat never][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951977/ekrecurrencerule-with-end-repeat-never

Comment: Also see [Creating Reoccurring Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/CreatingRecurringEvents/CreatingRecurringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH3-SW1) in the _Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide._